# Used RVM to get latest, ruby -v still out of date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm

Very odd, I had a ruby app working in 1.9.3 for a few weeks, one machine reboot and it fails. I hit ruby -v and am told "1.8.7", well thats the reason its failing. No idea how that happened though...

Tried:

```
#rvm get stable
#rvm get 1.9.3-head
```

but still,

```
#ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [x86_64-linux]
```

Why is it not getting updated?

```
#rvm list rubies
rvm rubies

   ruby-1.9.3-head [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-1.9.3-p194 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

Note: none of the answers/comments have fixed the problem...yet it was down voted? Anyway i cannot even type "rvm" on some of the user accounts!

Comment: Did you tell RVM to use 1.9.3?

Comment: what is the command for that?

Comment: rvm use 1.9.3

RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.
You need to change your terminal settings to allow shell login.
Please visit https://rvm.io/workflow/screen/ for example.

Comment: If you are getting RVM is not a function, you are not sourcing it correctly in your bash profile. See the documentation at https://rvm.io/rvm/install/ for instructions on fixing this.

Comment: Unfortunatly none of these answers or comments has helped. I still cant access the RVM on my user account. I have attempted to follow the tutorial at rvm.io but it still does not work. How do i allow RVM to be used on a user account?

Answer (score 2):

This command will set the the ruby 1.9.3-head as default for whole system.

```
rvm use 1.9.3-head --default
```

or use the ruby version you want to set as default instead of `1.9.3-head`  in above command

if you want to use it for project only specific , create .rvmrc file and speccify the details as below

go in app directory

```
echo rvm use ruby-1.9.3-head@projectname --create > .rvmrc
```

This will create a gemset named `projectname` and will be used everytime you go to this direcory.

Also have a look at the [cheatsheet](http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/rvm/) .It explains rvm usage in simple way.

Answer (score 1):

You can type

```
rvm use 1.9.3 --default
```

So it make ruby 1.9.3 as default ruby, you can also switch between multiple versions of ruby use

```
rvm use version
```

You can create a .rvmrc file in your project folder and write

```
rvm use 1.9.3
```

So, everytime you cd to your project folder, the specified ruby version in your .rvmrc file is used. Adding to this create a gemset say project_name and then update the .rvmrc file with

```
rvm use 1.9.3@project_name
```

Which will make things more clear ruby version with the proper gems are loaded when you enter the project folder.